# How do I configure facet items to remain visible when they are selected?

Tags: theming, commerce, search

I'm using Commerce Search API along with Search API and Facet API to provide a search for my products. For the server I'm using Search API Solr search.

I want to configure the facets for the search to remain visible when selected. As the facets are now, when I select one it disappears.

Although it seems that this should be an easy task to do, after searching around I couldn't find any information on how to successfully do this. If anyone has experience with this or an idea to make it work your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Go to "Configuration » Search and metadata » Search API" and click the facets tab. Next to the desired facets you will see "configure filters" with an arrow pointing down next to it. Click the arrow. In the drop down select "configure filters". Make sure that "Do not display active items" is NOT selected. This worked for me.